# how can i read the output from C# process before the process end?

Tags: c#

i want to create IDE for python that can run line by line like anaconda.
so i want return the output after each python command .

Edit: the solution is:

```cs
public Process cmd = new Process();
public  string output = "";
{
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i";//this was the problem
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender2, e2) =>
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e2.Data))
    {
        output += e2.Data.ToString()+"\n";

    }
});
cmd.Start();
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

{
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(result);//the output will take some time to complete
}
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately

Answer (score -1, accepted):

register to the OutputDataReceived event to get data :

```
    cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            // do what you need with the output (for instance append output)
        }
    });
```

and after cmd.Start() add:

```
   cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

this causes the process to read the redirected output..

so the final code would be:

```
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"python.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                // do what you need with the output (for instance append output)
                cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("python comand 1");
                cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("python comand 2");
                cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("another comand 3");

            }
        });
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

the exe I'm running basically has a button that on click writes a line to the console, and then reads 3 lines, so the event gets data "my output", and bla1,bla2 and bla3 get the values I wrote to the input:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("my output");
        string bla = Console.ReadLine();
        string bla2 = Console.ReadLine();
        string bla3 = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: more details please , i have tried this solution and it didn't work.

Comment: there was another line missing, I edited the answer

Comment: i retry this and it didn't work.

i have edited the question to your answer.

Comment: can you upload your project ?
i tried what you said and there is no output.
i should close the process so that the output appear.

Comment: edited to show what's going on in the exe I'm running.. right now do you have a problem with the input \ output or both?

Comment: i have a problem in the output only.
specifically when i want to see the output before the process closed.
when the process closed i can easily return all the outputs. but i don't want that.

Comment: just realized you're running python code - added a line to set argument - try that

Comment: yes i try to create somthing like anaconda that run a cell of code at a time and see the output from it..
you want me to try what ??

Comment: cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-u";

Comment: please upload the project.
i didn't understand the edited code.

Comment: in the c# code, I just added the third line, that sets an argument for the process. 
"-u" forces the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;

Comment: wooow i finally works . thanks alot.

Comment: cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-i"; not u